# Rewriting this simple javascript game as an example of AMD

Tags: javascript, amd

I've created a very simple "game" for guessing a word in Javascript. I say simple because it is basically a series of functions that do some DOM manipulation. I'm aware this code is of a fairly low standard as I've just started with Javascript but I want to rewrite it using an AMD framework.

This is primarily a learning exercise for me to get to grips with AMD which I realise seems to be a fairly advanced / involved approach to Javascript.

My question is, at a fairly high level, how do I move away from what I have which is here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32332055/hangman.html

and begin the task of implementing an AMD approach to this simple game.

Comment: You should start by breaking it up into Modules within the same file.   You should first become intimately familiar with the Module pattern and effective use of functions for scoping since AMD is relatively simple on top of those but will be overwhelming if you don't understand them.  And also you should try to move towards more abstract code within the functions rather than working on the DOM (which can be done in something closer to the calling app).  Overall you don't have many well defined boundaries, you should be limiting the view and scope of your code into discrete blocks.

Comment: Yes agreeing, with Matt, you might start by breaking your code up in to two modules.  One that handles dom parsing and invalidation (should something not exist in the dom) and a module, or maybe a "class" for your game.  Refactoring is often a gradual process.